# SolrSpellChecker returning suggestions for words present in index

Tags: solr, lucene, spell-checking

I am trying to do spell check with Solr.I am able to get suggestions when the word is incorrectly spelled. 
Eg:-word entered(incorrectly) : **maintaan**
I am getting "**maintain**" as suggestion,but if I query **maintain**,it is providing **maintaining** as suggestion even though  **maintain** is present in the index.

**solrConfig:**

```
 <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
<lst name="spellchecker">
<str name="name">default</str>
<str name="field">spell_text</str>
<str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
<str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.LevensteinDistance</str>
<float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
 <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>  

</lst>


    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">spellcheck_en</str>
      <str name="field">spell_text</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>

      <str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.LevensteinDistance</str>

      <str name="accuracy">0.5</str>

      <int name="maxEdits">1</int>

      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>

      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>

      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>

      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">.01</float>

        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">0.001</float>

           <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>

    </lst>

<lst name="spellchecker">
<str name="name">wordbreak</str>
<str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>
<str name="field">spell_text</str>
<str name="combineWords">true</str>
<str name="breakWords">true</str>
<int name="maxChanges">5</int>
    <int name="minBreakLength">5</int>
         <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>

</lst>

</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/spell" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">spellcheck_en</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
    <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">2</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">100</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">1</str>
         <str name="spellcheck">true</str>

  </lst>
  <arr name="last-components">
    <str>spellcheck</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

How can I ignore the suggestions for query words that are present in index.

Comment: According to the docs 'Only query words, which are absent in index or too rare ones (below maxQueryFrequency ) are considered as misspelled and used for finding suggestions'. Did you check the words you're searching have frequency above maxQueryFrequency?

Comment: I read this details in the Solr document,the word **maintain** occurs 6 times in the index.

Comment: Ok, but you're using a percentage and not an absolute value as `maxQueryFrequency`, so you're only ignoring words which frequency is higher than 1%.

Comment: So the correct way is to add `<float name="maxQueryFrequency">1</float>` within the dictionaries written in the search handler?

Comment: If you add 1 than any word with a count less than 1 will be spell checked.

Comment: I did the changes,still returning suggestions for words present in the index.

Comment: How did you change it?

Comment: I was to fix the problem my removing  `<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>` and `<str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">2</str>` .